# Fullcalendar events for use on DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, fullcalendar

I'm looking for a solution calendar, allowing me to add add a calendar event taken from an API (AJX json) and that these events have an onClick event that will allow me to spend an action (taking data json, filter and fill an object jquery DataTable.

- Load the page
- Check that no data on the LocalStorage. If there are no
  charge from the API, and store data in the LocalStorage
- We rendered the month in the calendar, and every day shows the events available according to the database, for each day.
- If the user clicks on any of these events, onClick will get data from another table (if not localStorage, ask the API and then keep on localStorage) and select the data elements corresponding to the par day / item.

According to the documentation I think it's possible. If anyone has experience about something, serious appreciate your advice.